# PHP placeholders

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query = '
PREPARE statement FROM
"INSERT INTO games_new
(
    gamedate,
    hometeam,
    visitors,
    result,
    matchreport,
    battedfirst,
    fieldedfirst,
    battedfirstruns,
    battedfirstextras,
    battedfirsttotal,
    battedsecond,
    fieldedsecond,
    battedsecondruns,
    battedsecondextras,
    battedsecondtotal
)
VALUES
(
    ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?
)
"';
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {die("Database access failed: " . mysql_error());}
$query =
'SET @gamedate = $_POST["gamedate"],' .
'@hometeam = $_POST["hometeam"],' .
'@visitors = $_POST["visitors"],' .
'@result = $_POST["result"],' .
'@matchreport = $_POST["matchreport"],' .
'@battedfirst = $_POST["battedfirst"],' .
'@fieldedfirst = $_POST["fieldedfirst"],' .
'@battedfirstruns = $_POST["battedfirstruns"],' .
'@battedfirstextras = $_POST["battedfirstextras"],' .
'@battedfirsttotal = $_POST["battedfirsttotal"],' .
'@battedsecond = $_POST["battedsecond"],' .
'@fieldedsecond = $_POST["fieldedsecond"],' .
'@battedsecondruns = $_POST["battedsecondruns"],' .
'@battedsecondextras = $_POST["battedsecondextras"],' .
'@battedsecondtotal = $_POST["battedsecondtotal"]'
;
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {die("Database access failed: " . mysql_error());}
$query = '
EXECUTE statement USING
    @gamedate,
    @hometeam,
    @visitors,
    @result,
    @matchreport,
    @battedfirst,
    @fieldedfirst,
    @battedfirstruns,
    @battedfirstextras,
    @battedfirsttotal,
    @battedsecond,
    @fieldedsecond,
    @battedsecondruns,
    @battedsecondextras,
    @battedsecondtotal
';
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {die("Database access failed: " . mysql_error());}
$query = 'DEALLOCATE PREPARE statement';
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {die("Database access failed: " . mysql_error());}
```

I am getting this syntax error :

> Database access failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
>   the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '["gamedate"],@hometeam =
>   $_POST["hometeam"],@visitors = $_POST["visitors"],@resu'

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: You're STILL vulnerable to sql injection, because you're first stuffing _POST data int your `SET` query. You've gained absolutely NO security by using placeholders utterly incorrectly.

Comment: Any ideas? Yes. You just copy and concocted something together without ever looking at the manual.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, learn the difference between single (`'`) and double (`"`) [quoted strings in php](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Secondly, `mysql_` functions [aren't recommended](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) to be used anymore. Use [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php).

So you should use:

```
"SET @gamedate = '{$_POST['gamedate']}'"
```

instead of escaping with `'`. Or rather do:

```
'SET @gamedate = "' . mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['gamedate'], $conn) . '"'
```

Or you can do it the right way (e.g. using [`PDO::prepare`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)):

```
$sql = 'SET @gamedate = :gamedate';
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql); // $dbh is instance of PDO
$sth->execute(array(':gamedate' => '...'));
```

Answer (score 4):

For this use:

```
mysqli_prepare ( $link , $query );
```

Example:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "pwd", "db");
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "INSERT INTO games_new
( gamedate, hometeam, visitors, result, matchreport, battedfirst, fieldedfirst, battedfirstruns, battedfirstextras, battedfirsttotal, battedsecond, fieldedsecond, battedsecondruns, battedsecondextras, battedsecondtotal )
VALUES
(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssssssssssssss",
    $_POST["hometeam"],
    $_POST["visitors"],
    $_POST["result"],
    $_POST["matchreport"],
    $_POST["battedfirst"],
    $_POST["fieldedfirst"],
    $_POST["battedfirstruns"],
    $_POST["battedfirstextras"],
    $_POST["battedfirsttotal"],
    $_POST["battedsecond"],
    $_POST["fieldedsecond"],
    $_POST["battedsecondruns"],
    $_POST["battedsecondextras"],
    $_POST["battedsecondtotal"]
);

mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
mysqli_close($link);
```

Comment: +1 for `mysqli`. This is the only safe way to do it. Named placeholders are a bit easier to work with, but this does the job.

Comment: It's not "the only safe way to do it". PDO's better.

Comment: I mean using placeholders like `?`, not `mysqli` specifically.

Comment: I don't understand why people use unnamed placeholders. Just seems like it's asking for errors. Insight?

Comment: @Stephane MySQLi doesn't support named placeholders like PDO does.

Comment: @ceejayoz Ouch, I didn't know that. That's painful. At least now I know why people are using unnamed placeholders. Thanks!

Comment: @Stephane Yeah, it's a pretty painful state of affairs there. Switching people to PDO usually makes them pretty happy.

Answer (score 1):

```
$query =
'SET @gamedate = $_POST["gamedate"],' .
```

Because this is in single quotes, `$_POST["gamedate"]` isn't evaluated. You should be doing:

```
$query =
"SET @gamedate = {$_POST['gamedate']}," .
```

However, using `$_POST` parameters directly like that **will** get your site hacked via SQL injection eventually.

Comment: Please don't "fix" code like this that then enables gigantic SQL injection holes. If you must, use `mysql_real_escape_string` to demonstrate how to write working code.

Comment: Hence the note, @tadman. The basic problem here is single quotes versus double quotes, which he needs to learn regardless of SQL injection issues.

Comment: If you're going to fix it, at least fix it. `"SET @gamedate = {$_POST['gamedate']},"` isn't even close to working SQL.

Comment: Depends on what the `$_POST` parameter is. `SET @gamedate = 1;` executes perfectly fine on my MySQL install. Unsafe, certainly, but works.

Comment: This is **precisely** why you **always** escape things. It's a `$_POST` parameter. You cannot reasonably assume anything about it. Leaving it unescaped is simply incorrect.

Comment: Which, again, FFS, is why I noted that he's going to get SQL injection doing things this way.

Comment: Yes, downvoted because you offered indirect help. "Here's how I wouldn't do it!"

Answer (score -2):

```
'@battedsecond = $_POST["battedsecond"],'
```

Since you are using simple quotes, you can't put variables directly into your string. Either use double quote, or use concatenation.

```
"@battedsecond = {$_POST["battedsecond"]},"
//OR
'@battedsecond = '.$_POST["battedsecond"].','
```